# How to delete rows, only if they are identical to the rows above and below?

Tags: r

I have a large dataframe, where each row is a different series of letters, except the first four rows, which contain identifiers.

I am trying to keep only the first and last occurrence of an identical row (from column 5 onwards) next to each other, in a large data frame (~30,000 rows, ~200 columns).
In other words, how do I delete all but the first and last identical consecutive row?

I've looked around, but the only code I can find keeps only one copy of each duplicate.

Making a simplified example, of what I want to do.

```
Data <- data.frame(Met = c("qwr", "asd", "zxc", "ert", "dfg", "cvb", 
                           "tyu", "fgh", "vbn", "uio", "jkl", "bnm"),
                   A = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2),
                   B = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2),
                   C = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2),
                   D = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2)
    )

Data

   Met A B C D
1  qwr 1 1 1 1
2  asd 2 2 2 2
3  zxc 2 2 2 2
4  ert 2 2 2 2
5  dfg 3 3 3 3
6  cvb 3 3 3 3
7  tyu 3 3 3 3
8  fgh 4 4 4 4
9  vbn 4 4 4 4
10 uio 2 2 2 2
11 jkl 2 2 2 2
12 bnm 2 2 2 2
```

Would become:

```
End

  Met A B C D
1 qwr 1 1 1 1
2 asd 2 2 2 2
3 ert 2 2 2 2
4 dfg 3 3 3 3
5 tyu 3 3 3 3
6 fgh 4 4 4 4
7 vbn 4 4 4 4
8 uio 2 2 2 2
9 bnm 2 2 2 2
```

I've been playing with this problem in different ways, but don't feel as if I've got anywhere close. I am most comfortable in R, but am willing to try other languages.

Comment: What defines what is a duplicate, e.g. which `Met` value is the one which gets retained?

Comment: *"(from column 5 onwards)"* What do you mean by that? Your sample data has only 5 columns. How do you define a duplicate row?

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you are trying to do is remove consecutive occurrence of 4 columns. We can combine the 4 columns using `unite` and use `data.table::rleid` to have an id for consecutive occurrence and select only 1st and last row in each group.

```
library(dplyr)
Data %>%
   tidyr::unite(temp, names(Data)[-1], remove = FALSE) %>%
   group_by(group = data.table::rleid(temp)) %>%
   slice(if(n() > 1) c(1L,n()) else 1L) %>%
   ungroup() %>%
   select(-temp, -group)

#   Met     A     B     C     D
#  <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 qwr       1     1     1     1
#2 asd       2     2     2     2
#3 ert       2     2     2     2
#4 dfg       3     3     3     3
#5 tyu       3     3     3     3
#6 fgh       4     4     4     4
#7 vbn       4     4     4     4
#8 uio       2     2     2     2
#9 bnm       2     2     2     2
```

---

Or a simpler approach suggested by @thelatemail is to use `rleidv` with `duplicated`

```
inds <- data.table::rleidv(Data[-1])
Data[!duplicated(inds) | !duplicated(inds, fromLast = TRUE), ]
```

Comment: You can avoid all the `unite` bits - `rleidv(Data[-1])` - might be speedier to use `duplicated` forwards and backwards on the generated variable too, though I haven't checked that.

Comment: @thelatemail yes, you are right. I was trying something similar earlier but I didn't know `rleidv`. This is much cleaner. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach this is to add in row numbers and dplyr's group_by to then select the min and max row number within that group.

It's unclear whether you want to group_by the first four columns or everything but the first four columns, but this code is easily modified in either case (just change the range of columns you give in the form first_included:last_included). Be sure to exclude the row number column in either case.

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
Data %>% 
   mutate(row.id = row_number()) %>% 
   group_by_at(vars(fifth.col:last.col)) %>% 
   filter(row.id == max(row.id) || row.id == min(row.id)) %>% 
   ungroup %>% 
   select(-row.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
inds = ave(1:NROW(Data),
           with(rle(Reduce(paste, Data[-1])), rep(seq_along(values), lengths)),
           FUN = function(x){
               id = seq_along(x)
               id %in% range(id)
           }) == 1
Data[inds,]
#   Met A B C D
#1  qwr 1 1 1 1
#2  asd 2 2 2 2
#4  ert 2 2 2 2
#5  dfg 3 3 3 3
#7  tyu 3 3 3 3
#8  fgh 4 4 4 4
#9  vbn 4 4 4 4
#10 uio 2 2 2 2
#12 bnm 2 2 2 2
```